# Calculate $\int_{C_2(0)} \frac{z}{(9-z^2)(z+i)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate $$\int_{C_2(0)} \frac{z}{(9-z^2)(z+i)}$$ where $C_2(0)$ is the circle of radius $2$ centered at $0$. I tried breaking up the integrand into its partial fraction decomposition $$\frac{z}{(9-z^2)(z+i)}=\frac{A}{3-z}+ \frac{B}{3+z}+ \frac{C}{z+i} \,\, (\star)$$ so that I may apply Cauchy's integral formula, but when I solve for $A$,$B$ and $C$, I get very messy values. After doing a little Algebra with the right hand side of $(\star)$, I get $$z=A(3+z)(z+i)+B(3-z)(z+i)+C(3-z)(3+z).$$ Then I try setting $z=-3$ to solve for $B$, $z=3$ to solve for $A$ and $z=-i$ to solve for $C$. Is this correct? I end up with ugly values that don't seem to make the problem any easier.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the residue theorem?

Comment: @starfall I don't think we've been introduced to it yet, just Cauchy's integral theorems and formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the singularities at $\pm 3$ are irrelevant (why?). And
$$\frac{z}{(9-z^2)(z+i)} = \frac{z/(9-z^2)}{(z- (-i))}.$$

Comment: I can see that $3 \not\in D_2(0)$ since $\left|3 \right|^2=9 > 4$, do we have to worry about $-i$ too?

Comment: @StVincent Not "too", but *only*: that's the only pole of the integrand within the domain enclosed by $\;C_2(0)\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo Ah, right. Thanks for the help